# Merging php application into JSF application

Tags: php, jsf

Please help me in the solution of this problem
I have developed a JSF web app, say JSFApp. And the team has developed a php application, say phpApp.

We need to merge both applications and run them on same servers, apache tomcat(please refer if any other is preferable).

The two apps dont even need to communicate with each other.

We could have bought two different domain names for the two web apps but we want to deploy both under same domain name.

We want to do something like copying the phpApp into JSFApp's webcontent folder and accessing it as localhost:8080/JSFApp/phpApp. We haven't tried it yet.

Please suggest.

Comment: Sorry, do you have the slightest idea about running applications? While your JSF either runs on a ServletEngine or an ApplicationServer, the PHP application needs a totally different runtime environment which needs to be set up separately. My suggestion: Get yourself an application architect and a sysadmin worth their money. While it is technically possible to run PHP applications in Tomcat, I strongly advise against it. Back to the drawings.

Comment: Hi Mark, I know about that, please understand that thats why I want help :)

Comment: Its because I am java j2ee guy, and I have to run php webapp in the same domain name as jsf one, so I thought i wud be better if I can put php app insode jsf's directory and then run(if its possible)...thanks :)

Comment: Like I said: back to drawing. I really fail to see a valid use case. You should set up a ServletContainer/AppServer and a runtime for PHP separately and use a reverse proxy to map the URLs to the respective backend.

Comment: Thanks Markus, I will research that :)

Comment: Apache httpd or varnish should be your best bets. I'd go with the latter, as it has a powerful caching option for static content, boosting your speed.

Comment: Hi All,I did the homework today and am stuck . its because its first time I will be hosting website. My are proficient in J2EE but naive in php. I will explain the problem and the potentials solutions that I think based on your replies and my homework. The requirement is: Say my web domain name is www.demo.com , I have created a jsf web app called demojsf and I have got php web app called demophp from a friend. Now, I am running my demojsf on my local system as localhost:8080/demojsf and being naive to php I dont even know how to run it , probably it may be localhost:80/demophp(so I think)

Comment: So,based upon your help I came up with following approaches as solution(or I think them as solutions): 1) install apache tomcat with demojsf and wamp with demophp on my server(which I will get from the web hosting service, that I think), now that means www.demo.com = localhost:8080/demojsf , then how will I deploy demophp, coz it needs localhost:80/demophp as the value for demo.com.........2) use php java bridge ? I need some starting help on this one, all I knew is that it acts as webservice between java and php.....The two apps donot need to communicate....please suggest .....thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had to support legacy PHP applications on Tomcat before. The solution I went with was to use [PHP/Java Bridge](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/index.php). See section *"I want to use PHP for all tomcat applications. Apache and IIS are not available, but performance is important. How do I install it?"* of the [FAQ](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/FAQ.html).

This works with Tomcat 6 and 7, it will not work with Tomcat 8.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I am researching over this. :)

Comment: Hi Mark, Is the following approach feasible ?                                                         The same server can easily support both PHP/Apache and Tomcat as separate services. In other words, the same host (e.g. www.myserver.com) can easily run Apache/PHP (e.g. http://www.myserver.com:80) and Tomcat (e.g. http://www.myserver.com:8080) concurrently. This is a very common configuration

Comment: Running on the same domain name does not mean you have to run in the same server…

Comment: Hi All,      I did the homework today and am stuck . I will explain the problem and the potentials solutions that I think based on your replies and my  homework.

Comment: Hi All,I did the homework today and am stuck . its because its first time I will be hosting website. My are proficient in J2EE but naive in php.  I will explain the problem and the potentials solutions that I think based on your replies and my  homework.  The requirement is:  Say my web domain name is www.demo.com , I have created a jsf web app called demojsf and I have got php web app called demophp from a friend. Now, I am running my demojsf on my local system as localhost:8080/demojsf and being naive to php I dont even know how to run it , probably it may be localhost:80/demophp(so I think)

Comment: So,based upon your help I came up with following approaches as solution(or I think them as solutions):  1) install apache tomcat with demojsf and wamp with demophp on my server(which I will get from the web hosting service, that I think), now that means www.demo.com = localhost:8080/demojsf , then how will I deploy demophp, coz it needs localhost:80/demophp as the value for demo.com..........................2) use php java bridge ? I need some starting help on this one, all I knew is that it acts as webservice between java and php.........please suggest .....thanks